# printtool keeps requesting admin to modify admin settings

Tags: printing

Im running OSX 10.13.x. Using a standard user account (not admin).

If i have a printer window open, i keep getting a popup that asks for administrators privileges to "Printtool is trying to modify the printer settings" (see attached screenshot).

If i close this popup i can still print fine, but it keeps popping up every minute or so until i close the print window.

Any ideas why this is happening and what i can do to stop it ?

The screenshot in question is for an HP laser jet printer, but i get the same 
issue for a range of different printers, so believe its something to do with OSX rather than the printer/s.

[image: screenshot of print window and popup requiring admin user]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your user to the Print Administrators group in terminal:

`sudo dseditgroup -o edit -n /Local/Default -a <username> -t user _lpadmin`

[Thanks @Mike P.]

Comment: Is there anyway this can be done via GUI ? Also what additional tasks can a Print Admin do that a standard use can not ?

Comment: I don't think so; it's not too scary, just open terminal, enter that command and then the admin user password. As for the other question, it just allows you to manage printers, queues etc. Why you can't do it now without continual nagging, I'm not sure, but this should fix the issue you have :)

Comment: -t user  (not group)

Comment: I was logged in as a guest user. just check it put before hustling.

Comment: I was logged in as a guest. just mentioning it as a check

Comment: @sam GUI instructions here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7269124; TLDR: Directory Editor app

Answer (score 4):

from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7269124:

#### Terminal

`sudo dseditgroup -o edit -n /Local/Default -a USERNAME -t user _lpadmin`

#### GUI

1. Open spotlight (`cmd-space`) and search for Directory Utility
2. Click the lock to make changes, then select Directory Editor, then select Groups from the Viewing popup menu.
3. Type `print` in the search field to quickly access Print Administrators. Select Print Administrators, then GroupMembership.
4. Click the *very subtle* “+” at the right side of the GroupMembership line, then type the name of the user overwriting “new_value” which is already selected, just waiting on you to type.
5. Save and quit Directory Utility. I’m not sure if it takes effect immediately or if you need to log the user out and back in.