# How Can I Recreate the CUPS _lpadmin (Print Administrator) group in MacOS X?

Tags: macos, permission, user-account, printing, cups

I was following [this advice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408967/475918) to add a user to the _lpadmin group on my system to stop getting a prompt to authenticate when trying to change print options.

Unfortunately, I clicked in the wrong place while using Directory Utility and deleted the entire Print Administrator group.

Now, no users on my system have privileges to change print options or reset the printing system, because none of the users are members of the group that no longer exists.

I tried creating the group "_lpadmin" manually in Directory Services, to no avail. Using the dseditgroup command to add a user to the group returns "Group not found."

Is there a way to reinstall the default CUPS system without reinstalling my entire OS?

Comment: Reinstalling the OS is non-destructive, just do that.